# WSO2 API Manager 4.1.0 - Unable to update api-manager.xml

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

1. Downloaded WSO2 API Manager 4.1.0 Zip Archive
2. Navigated to APIM\wso2am-4.1.0\wso2am-4.1.0\repository\conf\api-manager.xml
3. Updated the api-manager.xml for JWTConfiguration and set EnableJWTGeneration to

   **true**
4. save the api-manager.xml changes and restarted the server.
5. after restarting the server the api-manager.xml changes are reverting back to old values

   **false**
6. Why changes are not reflecting in api-manager.xml?
7. Help us how to update api-manager.xml

Answer (score 3):

Do not change xml configuration files directly, you should be changing `deployment.toml` instead.

Complete list of options can be found [here](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/config-catalog/)

Read more about this behaviuor at [Understanding the new configuration model](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/understanding-the-new-configuration-model/#understanding-the-new-configuration-model)

Answer (score 0):

Edit APIM\wso2am-4.1.0\wso2am-4.1.0\repository\conf\deployment.toml

remove '#' before

[apim.jwt]

enable = true

then restart APIM

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).